# How to write a for-generate statement to generate multiple instances of this parallel sorting network circuit?

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, vhdl, parallel, algorithm

I'm trying to implement a parallel sorting network. I'm curious to how one would write a for-generate statement to generate 128 instances of this sorting circuit?

It's supposed to sort 256 8-bit numbers from least to greatest without a clock using only combinational logic.

This is a link to the paper on the sorting network I'm trying to use:

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261152327_Zero-delay_FPGA-based_odd-even_sorting_network?enrichId=rgreq-27e12d3d7cce338ad2cbbdffa750edb4-XXX&enrichSource=Y292ZXJQYWdlOzI2MTE1MjMyNztBUzoyMzg2MDc5Njk1NTAzNDNAMTQzMzg5OTk4MTg4Nw%3D%3D&el=1_x_3&_esc=publicationCoverPdf

Links to the circuit and sorting network diagram are below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need the VHDL entity for that sorter (or a VHDL wrapper for it if it isn't already in VHDL), and a clear idea how to describe the interconnections into and between sorters as a function of the generate statement's "loop variable". Then you are ready to go ahead.

Comment: Start small - how would you do it with 4 bit numbers and only two of them? Then expand to four numbers. Take what you learn and move bigger.

Comment: 3 different parallel sorting algorithms have been implemented in the [PoC-Library](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC): e.g. [Odd-Even Merge-Sort](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/sort/sortnet/sortnet_OddEvenMergeSort.vhdl?ts=2). The size of the sorting network can be configured via generics.

Comment: I hope it is an academic exercise. You will have difficulties getting that in an FPGA. I just did a short paper analysis. You need a lot of intermediate 8-bit wide buses. The indices get much easier if you re-name the top/bottom wire bus in each odd stage.

Comment: Yes, this is mainly for learning purposes only.

Answer (score 1):

I like a challenge and it took me a few tries but I got it working for W bits wide data and D inputs. (D is a power of two).  I cheated a bit because I am rather more proficient with Verilog. This is the RTL View Xilinx gave me:

[image]

I am not giving away the code if only to prevent this website to become a 'Look: free code!' but I can give some tips:

I started with defining D*(D+1) 8-bit buses. This makes that I can use the same bus name everywhere in my generate.

Connect the first D buses to your inputs, the last D buses to your outputs.

In the odd stage you pass two buses along which makes the bus indices very nasty. A simple solution is that at the top and bottom of each odd state I rename the bus. For the top bus this is:
`assign bus[stage*d+d] = bus[stage*d];`
Now you always have D buses per stage an all loops become regular for loops.